# PHP sessions not working at all

Tags: php, session

I have tested php sessions with this function

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'][] = time();

header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r($_SESSION);
```

In theory, it should return one more array element each time I reload the page. But in my case, for some reason, it always displays a single element.

So I'm stuck, please help!

**UPDATED**

PHP version on my server is 5.3.13
Here is what i have in session section
[image]

Comment: Seems like it shouldn't be required, but I would at least try initializing the Array.

Comment: Try to get rid of the `[]`.

Comment: Seems like a browser protection kind of thing to me, since sessions are saved on the client side. Might be wrong tho. You can always do it the old fashion way

Comment: @Fred he is trying to append to the ['test'] array

Comment: @sircapsalot got it. Not enough `caffeine` yet. Need an extra `100 cc's`, stat!

Comment: @php_nub_qq only the session id is stored on the user side. session data is stored on the server.

Comment: @php_nub_qq you are wrong, Session data is not handed to the user unless you do it on purpose(except the id), i think you're confusing sessions and cookies?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte And overwrite `$_SESSION['test']` every page load?  No.  Lots of poor advice here people.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. I get multiple elements. How about the rest of you? Tested it too?

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and it works for me too...

Comment: @sircapsalot Must be a server config issue on the OP's end, then(?)

Comment: What is your php version OP? it's possible that you are using an old version and ['array'][] isn't considered a push?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue via CLI where there is no persistent session. Are you able to save other session variables between page loads? If not, your sessions are not persistent.

Comment: My PHP version is `PHP Version 5.2.3` btw.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Is correct - sessions simply not being saved (`print_r` prior to appending to array will show `$_SESSION` is empty).  This is a server config issue...and op's question title is apt: *"PHP sessions not working at all"*

Comment: @artnikpro the silence leads me to believe that you are unsure how to check.  create a new php file with just the contents `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: @artnikpro - See what your results are with `sircapsalot's` comment about creating a `phpinfo` file. Look under `Session Support`, see if it is `enabled` under the **SESSION** header, as well as other settings pertinent to your issue.

Comment: If you can, check the file permissions of /var/php_sessions and look inside it to see if there are any recent files in there. That should tell you if the directory is readable.

Comment: @artnikpro - the only differences I can tell from yours and mine, are that my settings for `session.use_only_cookies` are both set to `off` and `session.bug_compat_42 = on` - `session.bug_compat_warn = on`.

Comment: `@OP` - I'm curious, do you have an `.htaccess` file in your root, with possible conflicting code in there, such as `session.cookie_lifetime` or anything else that could affect your sessions/cookies? Plus are you running `your own webserver`, or are you on a shared host?

Comment: @Fred, I have .htaccess file with a single line of code, but there's nothing related to sessions

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Got it, thanks George. Cheers

Comment: @artnikpro Then I for one, am stumped. If and when you do find a solution, post it as an **answer** for your question. I for one will be very curious to know why your server is acting up like that. They very well may have set certain restrictions. Keep us posted and good luck.

Comment: @Fred, I had contaced to the support team of my hosting, so they have changed `session.save_path` in php.ini. So now it works. The problem solved

Comment: @artnikpro Great, am glad the problem is solved. Since no one else thought of it, you should post it as an **answer**. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

A workaround to try...

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['test'])){
array_push($_SESSION['test'], time());}
else {
$_SESSION['test']= time();}

header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r($_SESSION);
```

If this doesn't work as well...then you may not have cookies enabled...

Comment: Cookies are enabled, of course. I have testes your code but it returns the same result as mine :(

Answer (score 0):

i have tried your code.... its works fine

```
<?php 

session_start();

$_SESSION['test'][] = time();

header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

> output ::Array
>   (
>       [test] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => 1370889004
>               [1] => 1370889023
>               [2] => 1370889024
>               [3] => 1370889025
>               [4] => 1370889025
>               [5] => 1370889025
>               [6] => 1370889025
>               [7] => 1370889026
>               [8] => 1370889026
>               [9] => 1370889026
>           ) )

can you please check if cookie is enabled or not?

Comment: Why is this in an answer? This has been said 50 times in the comments section.

Comment: @crush The answer here is, "make sure your browser is accepting cookies"..it's just disguised.

Comment: @crush - A `Brownie Points` gain perhaps? It needs formatting too.

Comment: @Madbreaks Seems like a comment more than an answer. It would be an answer if the OP had told us that cookies were not enabled. Now, it is simply conjecture. I agree, that it is one of the more likely answers, though.

Comment: Cookies are enabled - 100%. I checked in Chrome and FF

Comment: @artnikpro print $_COOKIE to be sure 200%

Comment: @kallolbasu here is what I have in cookies
Array
(
    [PHPSESSID] => daac7653fd743d4f40d8e1d16c1b3257
)

Comment: @artnikpro i have more info :: Array ( [__utma] => 111872281.105724712.1366833236.1370450211.1370888998.6 [__utmz] => 111872281.1366833236.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) [toolbarDisplay] => hide [__utmc] => 111872281 [PHPSESSID] => pl7cut16s0u4hlkaq6tg3jlnr4 )

Comment: @kallolbasu, I also have more info on cient side if I type `document.cookie` in console. But on server side just a single PHPSESSID

Comment: @artnikpro you can see different output in case u type http://localhost/testcode.php and http://127.0.0.1/testcode.php...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31544/discussion-between-kallol-basu-and-artnikpro)

Comment: @kallolbasu, I'm not on localhost, but on web-hosting. My project used to work fine but after I move it to another domain there becomes this issues with sessions.

Answer (score -3):

Try this way:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'][] = time();

header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: `print_r` echoes its argument by default, why ask for it to return a value and then echo it out?

Comment: The same results can be achieved by leaving the code exactly as the OP had it. This is not an answer and merely add's additional work.

Comment: My mistake. For some reason did not work until I put the echo. Now work both variants. Sorry for my bad english.